# Android Application send tag to contacless reader ISO 14443 A or B device

Tags: android, nfc

Can everyone know how to build android nfc application which can send some information to reader device ISO 14443 A / B?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

P2P is possible. The most challenging is to find out the right libraries/SDK and the commercial quality reader. So far we have tried already 3 open-source solutions (nfclib, ISMB, etc.) and none of them is really ready for commercial system roll-out.Now we have ordered 2 other NFC readers and SDKs - we waiting for them to be delivered for them to test them:(

Also the problem is the phone side - so far we have tested 5 NFC Android phones and each of them is behaving differently... For us the best will be reader that emulates NFC tags or MIFARE chips...

Petr

Comment: Hi @STeN: Technical Problems and hacking-solutions aside: Using Card Emulation from the host-cpu will never work because usually the UICC/eSE will open card-emulations. Two at the same time can't exist on the RF layer. So in short: Mobile payment makes user-mode card-emulation impossible.

Comment: That said: With the 3rd party solution I work on (commercial) I could in theory do ISO14443-A, ISO14443-B nd even FeliCa CE, but all that stuff will stop working and interferes in horrible ways as soon as you put an SWP/NFC enabled SIM card into your phone.

Comment: @STeN Can a acr122 device with libnfc be used to communicate with an android phone using android beam?

Comment: @STeN Also, can you please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871335/cross-platform-mobile-development-framework-for-nfcs and provide your valuable opinion