# Cross platform Mobile development framework for NFC's

Tags: mobile, cross-platform, nfc

I want to create an application for several mobile platforms (android, BB, iOS etc) which has the capability to use nfc peer to peer functionality. (for example, to read/write to a nfc reader/writer).

I looked at mosync (because it allows us to write C/C++ code which i'm comfortable with) but their API does not specify anything about peer-to-peer nfc. It only supports read/write to/from nfc tags.

So, which is the best platform that i can use to fulfill this need? (by best i mean flexible and which supports the maximum number of platforms)

Also, can libnfc be used with "any" such framework?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't plan to take advantage of the capabilities of the devices like a native app can, I suggest you to take a look at [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). When we talk about cross platform apps, it is the most common framework. Also you can use [phonegap-nfc](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc) plugin to support android, bb and windows phone 8.

Answer (score 2):

We have developed ~5 NFC applications for Android, iPhone and Windows Phone 8. We are starting BB10 now.

Do not count on cross-platform there - at the end you will not save either money nor effort. I have nothing against cross-platform and we heavily use it e.g. on Google TV or PS3, but not there.

It is simpler (at least for us) to quickly come with Android, iPhone (iCarte), Windows Phone 8 and possibly BB10 application done in native code. The content itself can be rendered with use of HTML/JavaScript/CSS.

BR
STeN